# Deleting smart Contract

Tags: contract-development

i have a particular problem with a smart contract: I have made some in a wrong way in the Ethereum Sandbox and now i want to delete them...but when i search the id of the contract to delete with "CustomContracts.find().fetch()" i couldn't find the id...

The only information i become is this:

```
CustomContracts.find().fetch()
[Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can delete a contract from the blockchain only if it was programmed to do so.